# Python Manim NumberLine Scaling Syntax

Tags: python, syntax, inverse, manim

Manim NumberLine object:
https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/reference/manim.mobject.graphing.number_line.NumberLine.html
Manim scale object:
https://docs.manim.community/en/stable/_modules/manim/mobject/graphing/scale.html

```
a = NumberLine(
    x_range=[-2.5, 2.5, 0.5],
    length=13,
    decimal_number_config={"num_decimal_places": 1},
    include_numbers=True,
    font_size = 50,
    tick_size = 0.2,
    scaling = LinearBase.function(lambda x:1/x)
)
```

I'm a novice coder, so I don't understand how to tell my numberline to scale the x_range, by reciprocating the values in the range.
What's the proper syntax to scale my number line, by inverting all the values in x_range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/ManimCommunity/manim/discussions/2758

Answered on GitHub by @behackl.

```
from typing import Iterable

from manim import *
from manim.mobject.graphing.scale import _ScaleBase

class InverseScale(_ScaleBase):
    def function(self, value: float) -> float:
        return 1 / value
    
    def inverse_function(self, value: float) -> float:
        return 1 / value
        
    def get_custom_labels(self, val_range: Iterable[float], unit_decimal_places=None) -> Iterable[Mobject]:
        label_array = [MathTex(r"%s" % float(np.around(v,1)), color = "#FF40FF") for v in val_range]
        label_array[20] = MathTex('undef')
#         label_array = [MathTex('undef') if i == MathTex('inf') else i for i in label_array]
        return label_array
```

Create a custom class.